# Extract specific values from lists in a dictionary

Tags: python

I have a dictionary

```
d = {'B201': ['Alex', ' 10', 'Poor'],
     'N298': ['Smith', ' 100', 'Aboveaverage'],
     'N200': ['John', ' 98', 'Verygood'],
     'B299': ['Mike', ' 4', 'Excellent']}
```

I want to extract names and store them into `x`, i.e. (Alex, Smith, John, Mike) and in another `y` variable I want to store Poor, Aboveaverage, Verygood, Excellent.

How can I achieve this task, as I am unable to select specific values from the dictionary using keys?

I tried executing `d.values()`,
but it is returning `dict_values([['Alex', ' 10', 'Poor'], ['Smith', ' 100', 'Aboveaverage'], ['John', ' 98', 'Verygood'], ['Mike', ' 4', 'Excellent']])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all the names:

```
x = []
for value in d.values():
    x.append(value[0])
```

or more simply, using a list comprehension:

```
x = [value[0] for value in d.values()]
```

I think you can figure out how you can do the same for the `y` values.

Answer (score 1):

#### Options

You can use [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
x = [entry[0] for entry in d.values()]
y = [entry[2] for entry in d.values()]
```

Or you can iterate over the dictionary values:

```
x = []
y = []
for entry in d.values():
    x.append(entry[0])
    y.append(entry[2])
```

If you want to get a bit more elegant you can use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
x, _, y = zip(*d.values())
```

#### How the zip approach works

The `*` prefix operator passes the values in the iterable supplied to it as separate arguments, essentially making the call

```
zip(['Alex', ' 10', 'Poor'], ['Smith', ' 100', 'Aboveaverage'], ['John', ' 98', 'Verygood'], ['Mike', ' 4', 'Excellent'])
```

The `zip` function then returns a list containing the first element of each argument, a list containing the second element of each argument, etc. We assign these lists to `x` and `y`, plus a temporary variable named `_` that we ignore.

Comment: The zip answer is what I was going to post. It's not fancy, it's the most pythonic.

Comment: That description was a bit tongue-in-cheek. It's not the immediate solution that a lot of people will think of and it's a bit more elegant (especially compared to the loop).

Answer (score 0):

The values of the dict are arrays. If you know for sure that the first position from the array is the name you could iterate over the dictionary and append to `x` the `values[0]` and to `y` the `values[2]`. This is one easy to understand way to do it

```
  x = []
  y = []

  for v in d.values():
     x.append(v[0])
     y.append(v[2])
```

Comment: You could also use tuple unpacking to get the first and last values like so: `for name, _, status in d.values(): ...`